# One time login - Django

Tags: django, session, cookies

How to avoid frequent login in Django like "one time login". I read some methods using session and cookies but not for saving the user info. It will be helpful if you provide some code for this !!

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Explain some more about it. Is your session expiring too soon? You must log in again every time you reopen window? Or there are other issues? Do you use authentication/authorization built in django?

Comment: It must not ask every time to login. I am asking how to save the user session. authentication is to verify user is valid or not right ??

Comment: But are you using django authenticaton? If yes, it shouldn't ask every time. Please give more information, maybe some code from your application.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look up session middleware's 'set_expiry' function. Alternatively, you can use settings.SESSION_COOKIE_AGE.